# Javascript "clockwork arithmetic"

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to remember something called "clockwork arithmetic" in Javascript which I've read a long time ago in a tutorial about slideshows/carousels. (term might be wrong since I can't find anything useful in google)

It was a shorthand of the following code:

```
a = a + 1;
if (a > total) a = 0;
```

Essentially it was incrementing until it reached the total, and when it reached the total it would reset back to 0. This was mainly used to create carousels which would scroll indefinitely as it would always scroll back to the beginning (index 0).

Does anyone how to write the above 2 lines of code in 1 line using the said clockwork arithmetic? I think it used the "remainder" operator % but I don't remember much else.

Comment: So.. what's the question?

Comment: @chRyNaN although that achieves the same thing, it's not particularly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is called [modular arithmetic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic), and effectively is used in clocks:

> A familiar use of modular arithmetic is in the 12-hour clock, in which
>   the day is divided into two 12-hour periods. If the time is 7:00 now,
>   then 8 hours later it will be 3:00. Usual addition would suggest that
>   the later time should be 7 + 8 = 15, but this is not the answer
>   because clock time "wraps around" every 12 hours

In JavaScript, you can do [modulo operations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation) using the [`%` operator](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.5.3):

> The `%` operator yields the remainder of its operands from an implied
>   division; the left operand is the dividend and the right operand is
>   the divisor.

Some equivalent examples:

```js
a = (a+1) % total;
```

```js
a = ++a % total;
```

```js
++a, a %= total;
```

Comment: You could explain that the `%` operator stands for the modulo operator and that what the OP is looking to reproduce is called [Modular Arithmetic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic).

Answer (score 1):

I haven't had a chance to verify this yet, but I think it would look something like this:

```
a = a < total ? a++ : 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with a ternary, though I think this makes the code needlessly hard to read, and thus less maintainable, so I wouldn't use it.

```
a = a < total ? a + 1 : 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you want to loop around, a different one liner could be

```
current = min + (delta = (delta + step) % (max - min));
```

Here is an example in usage

```
function count(max, min, step) {
    if (typeof min !== 'number') min = 0;
    if (typeof step!== 'number') step = 1;
    var delta = -step;
    max = max - min;

    return function next() {
        return min + (delta = (delta + step) % max);
    };
}

var fn = count(4, 1, 1);
fn(); // 1
fn(); // 2
fn(); // 3
fn(); // 1
fn(); // 2
fn(); // 3
```

---

Similarly you can get to any iteration if you know how many steps (`i`) it is by using

```
current = min + ((step * i) % (max - min));
```